# Unable to automate an SQL query with date/time columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want an SQL query to generate previous month data but as the year changed I cannot do so. Can anyone help with the correct `case when` statement for my problem. I think it requires nested `case when` statements.

My columns are :

- `createdmonth`
- `createdyear`
- `currentmonth`
- `currentyear`

and I want to apply conditions on those columns.

Here is what I tried :

```
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','IST-05:30',u.createdTime))) as createdYear,
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','IST-05:30',getdate()))) as currentyear,
EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','IST-05:30',u.createdTime))) as createdmonth,
EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','IST-05:30',getdate()))) - 1 as currentmonth,

CASE WHEN currentmonth = 0 THEN 12 
    CASE WHEN createdyear = currentyear then createdyear - 1 else createdyear 
ELSE currentmonth end as currentmonthtime,
```

Comment: Please post fuller SQL code and not just extracted lines and post error message you receive.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! any sample data and expected output?

Comment: Mysql does not have GETDATE() are you actually using MSSQL/SQL-SERVER/T-SQL? and I don't think sql server has extract?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the DATE_ADD function, that should do what you are looking for:

```
DATE_ADD(whatever_your_date_column_is, INTERVAL -1 MONTH);
```